# Django signal conditionally update one table based on another

Tags: python, django, django-signals

I'm working on my first django project that is a sports betting game.

Here are my models:

```
class Game(models.Model):
    home_team = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    away_team = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    home_goals = models.IntegerField(default=None)
    away_goals = models.IntegerField(default=None)


class Bet(models.Model):
    gameid = models.ForeignKey(Game, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    userid = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    home_goals = models.IntegerField()
    away_goals = models.IntegerField()
    score = models.IntegerField(default=None, null=True)
```

First I create a game instance with null values in goals fields, then users make their bets.
Once the game is over, I update game goals fields. Now I need to assign points for each user like this:

```
WHEN bet.home_goals = game.home_goals AND bet.away_goals = game.away_goals THEN 2
WHEN game.home_goals > game.away_goals AND bet.home_goals > bet.away_goals THEN 1 
WHEN game.home_goals < game.away_goals AND bet.home_goals < bet.away_goals THEN 1 
WHEN bet.home_goals = bet.away_goals AND game.home_goals = game.away_goals THEN 1 
ELSE 0
```

It seems that I should create a POST_SAVE singal to update Bet.score for each user based on update of Game.home_goals and Game.away_goals? But I have no idea how to do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend staying away from Signals. Generally speaking, you should use Signals when:

- Multiple pieces of code are interested in the same event;
- You need to interact with a third-party code (where you have no direct access).

In your case, only the `Bet` model is interested in the `Game` save/change event. You have direct access to the `Game` class.

I'm saying that because signals tend to "hide" code/business logic of your application, making the maintenance harder (because it's not immediately obvious you have some code being executed).

For me it looks like a job for a regular view, where you would add the score of the game and "close" it. Maybe an extra field (could be a `BooleanField` or `DateTimeField`) to indicate that the `Game` is over.

See an example below:

**forms.py**

```
from .models import Game
from django import forms
from django.db import transaction

class GameForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Game
        fields = ('home_goals', 'away_goals')

    # do everything inside the same database transaction to make sure the data is consistent
    @transaction.atomic
    def save(self):            
        game = super().save(commit=True)
        for bet in game.bet_set.all():
            if bet.home_goals == game.home_goals and bet.away_goals == game.away_goals:
                bet.score = 2
            elif <build_your_logic_here>:
                bet.score = 1
            else:
                bet.score = 0
            bet.save()
        return game
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from .forms import GameForm

def end_game(request, game_id):
    game = Game.objects.get(pk=game_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = GameForm(request.POST, instance=game)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/gameboard/')  # add here the relevant url where to send the user
    else:
        form = GameForm(instance=game)

    return render(request, 'game_form.html', {'form': form})
```

If for some reason, the *score change event* happened from multiple points (that is, the model was updated by different parts of your application), in your case the best option would be overriding the `save()` method, like this:

**models.py**

```
class Game(models.Model):
    home_team = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    away_team = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    home_goals = models.IntegerField(default=None)
    away_goals = models.IntegerField(default=None)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # call the save method
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

        # execute your extra logic 
        for bet in self.bet_set.all():
            if bet.home_goals == self.home_goals and bet.away_goals == self.away_goals:
                bet.score = 2
            # rest of the if/else logic
            bet.save()
```

This would be a similar implementation than a Signal, but I would say more explicit. As I mentioned, I do not think this is the best implementation for your problem. This could potentially slow down your application, because this for loop would be executed every time you save a `Game` instance.

But, if you want to learn more about Signals, I've wrote a blog post about it: [How to Create Django Signals](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/28/how-to-create-django-signals.html).

Comment: thank you very much for this answer, it works like a charm and it is understandable for a rookie.
I've been strugling with this problem for over a week. You are my hero :)